# Access Class Name From a Class Method

Tags: python, class, methods

assuming the simple case where Foo is

```
class Foo:
    def some_func(self):
        print('hellow world')
```

I only have access to the variable func where func is :

```
func = Foo.some_func
```

I am trying to get the `Foo` class name from the variable `func`

```
func
Out[6]: <function __main__.Foo.some_func>
func.__class__.__name__
Out[7]: 'function'
```

I am expecting to get `Foo`  is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Not answering but just a note, you can find it from interpretor in help(func)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3 solution:

```
def get_class_name(func):
    return func.__qualname__.split('.')[0]
```

`__qualname__` method actually prints `Foo.some_func` for `func`.

Splitting the string by `.` and taking the first element, it should do the job.

Python 2 & 3 solution:

```
def get_class_name(func):
    return func.__str__().split('.')[0].split()[-1]
```

Edit:

In Python 3, `func.__str__()` prints `<function Foo.some_func at 0x10c456b70>`.

In Python 2, `func.__str__()` prints `<unbound method Foo.some_func>`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I am looking for. did not know about `__qualname__`

Comment: Me either. I was using ipython and looking up dunder methods that might be useful. I guess I learnt something today!

Comment: @StevenG may I ask what you are doing with this? Just interested in the use case of this.

Comment: I am using this in a decorator, the decorator is used in multiple classes which represents tasks. when the task.run() has been called, I get the task name ( the class name) and send a log to SQL

Comment: @StevenG Got it! Glad I can help with that!

Comment: I removed my comment prior to the last edit because I thought you got it covered with a precedent edit. NB, the first solution works for python >= 3.3.

Comment: `object.__str__(func)` works even when `func.__str__` is overridden.